# Is it worth to open multiple database connections for sql insertion

Tags: c#, mysql, database, performance, connection

I am writing a project related to mass data fetching.
Currently I am using .NET Framework 4.8 and the Mysql package to start connection and insert data to the database server.

I am going to insert around 400, 000 line/second.
I am concern that the SQL connection may become the bottleneck of my program.
I would like to know if I create a multitthread connection with the sql and insert the data using a consumer queue, would it be faster and is it worth it(pros and cons)?

In my intuitive thought it would be faster but I am not sure how much performance it can provide with respect of the overhead for threads. I am not a SQL expert so it would be nice if someone could explain the pros and cons of opening multiple connections to a SQL on multiple threads.

Comment: It is quite impossible to answer this in a generic way. 
400_000 per second is 34_560_000_000 per day. That is a lof of data.

Comment: I just want some idea of how much insertion speed could a new connection thread increase, or maybe some logic behind multiple connection to sql. It is ok not to have a very generic answer.

Comment: Mysql? How about https://medium.com/@benmorel/high-speed-inserts-with-mysql-9d3dcd76f723

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thanks for the article. It does give me some new vision to this problem but still I would like some informationi related to multiple connection.

Comment: I would think having multiple connections fighting over the ability to write to a table would make things slower, but perhaps that's not the case with MySQL.

Comment: All the inserted rows must end up on disk.  Are you using SSDs?  RAID?  Have you computed whether your I/O system can handle the number of bytes/second required?  Is the data coming from a file (as opposed to programmatically generated or the network); if so, that doubles the I/O.

Comment: What indexes are on the table?  They will not initially slow down the operation, but they will inhibit the long-term throughput.

Comment: How many rows will you insert all together?  How much RAM do you have?  Are the rows sorted by the PRIMARY KEY?  (These, and many more, questions need answering before getting to your question about multi-connection.)

Comment: @RickJames assume my workstation will have enough input as I will pack it to a docker solution and pass it to a server backend. It is a RAID 5 SSD data server. Datas are all fetched by webscrapping, API and websockets.

Comment: @Ibrennan208 In some of my smaller scale testing it improves the efficiency by a certain percentage but I am not quite sure why it happens.

Comment: @Ice - "why it happens" -- MySQL is written as single-threaded code; this leads to situations where separate connections can take advantage of things.  A big one is being blocked waiting for I/O.  Some of that is softened by doing most I/O in the background and by having a shared cache of disk blocks.  That leads to the Mutexes to keep from stumbling over each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rumors, opinions, hearsay, facts, version-dependent benchmarks, some personal experience, etc...

Multiple threads will improve throughput, but with limits:

- Throughput is capped at about half the theoretical limit.  (Your "certain percentage")  (This is based on benchmarks from a multi-threaded package; I forget the name; it was a decade ago.)
- Multiple threads will compete with each other over Mutexes and other necessary locking mechanisms.
- As of about 5.7, 64 threads was MySQL's limit for multi-threading; above that, throughput stalled or even dropped.  (Source: Many Oracle benchmarks bragging about how much better one version was than the previous.)  (Meanwhile, latency for each thread went through the roof.)
- Each thread should batch the data if possible.

Batching:

- `LOAD DATA` is the fastest way to `INSERT` lots of rows from a single thread at a single time.  But if you include the cost of writing the file to `LOAD`, that may make it effectively slower than batched inserting.
- Batched `INSERT` is a close second.  But it caps out at "hundreds" of rows, when it hits either some limit or "diminishing returns".
- Batched Inserting is 10 times as fast as inserting one row per `INSERT` query.  So it (or `LOAD DATA`) is worth using for high speed ingestion.  (Source: many *different* timed tests.)

Source of data:

- Some data sources necessarily deliver only one row at a time (eg, sensor data from vehicles every N seconds.)  This begs from some intermediate layer to batch the data.
- A discussion of gathering data:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table

What happens after loading the data?  Surely this is not a write-only-never-read table.

- Normalization is useful for shrinking the disk footprint; this is best done in batches.  See [*Normalization*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization)
- `PARTITIONing` is rarely useful, except for eventual purging of old data.  See [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)
- A huge 'Fact' table is hard to search; consider building Summary data as you ingest he data: [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)
- It may even be practical to do the above processing, then toss the raw data.  It sounds like you might be acquiring a terabyte of data per day.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It does clarify a lot of SQL concept to me. This is a mass market data project and so I do need it to be stored for future analytic usage so I can't really dump the raw data but all the other points are amazing!